# Detect when the security panel has been closed?

Tags: apache-flex, flash

Is there a way to detect this in Flash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. There is a workaround though :

https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-41?focusedCommentId=187534&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#action_187534